# Where in the TLS 1.3 record is the sequence number located?

Tags: aes, tls, aes-gcm

The sequence number should be a 64 bit number in every TLS record, but the record header layer is only 5 bytes long and I am looking at a Wireshark pcap, where the TLS record only includes the header and encrypted application data. There is no sequence number.

Comment: As answered it is implicit, not transmitted. And the same for earlier TLS, and SSL. However, _datagram_ TLS -- _DTLS_ -- 1.0 and 1.2 corresponding respectively to TLS 1.1 and 1.2 do transmit it; there is no DTLS1.3, at least not yet.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence numbers are [never explicitly transmitted](https://serializethoughts.com/2016/02/09/tls-sequence-numbers), but are calculated independently by both sides starting from 0 with separate counts for send and receive.

Comment: So each outgoing TLS record increases the "sent sequence number" counter by 1 and each incoming TLS record increases the "received sequence number" by 1? Meaning, Wireshark must be counting how many times they see a TLS record (counting TLS headers perhaps)?

Comment: The client and server software are certainly doing this WireShark records [relative sequence numbers](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Relative_Sequence_Numbers) according to what it has observed AIUI

Comment: I am not sure if the TCP sequence number is the same as the sequence number of a TLS record - the one being used to XOR the IV in TLS 1.3 when decrypting AES.

Comment: That's right; the TLS sequence number only refers to TLS packets. Wireshark may not be tracking it at all.

Comment: Packets or TLS records? I think a TLS record can span several packets or a packet may contain several TLS records. I think you mean TLS records.

Comment: @DanielS: correction: the TLS sequence number refers to TLS *records*.  There is no necessary correlation between how records are laid out and how they fit within packets (e.g. TCP segments)

Comment: Agreed ((ignore this unnecessary comment extension))